# Python sorted() adds multiple of the same elements to list

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

I have a rather complicated data structure so I'll try my best to articulate...

The **tl;dr** version of this is I have a list of 2 items, run sorted and now I have 4 items in the list??

My custom class is:

```
class Additional(object):
    def __init__(self, tests): #tests is my complicated data structure
        self.tests = tests
        for test in self.tests:
            self.statement_coverage_tests.append(self.tests[test].get('statements'))
            self.branch_coverage_tests.append(self.tests[test].get('branches'))
        # sort the branch and statement by their coverage count
        # this is the culprit?
        sa = sorted(self.statement_coverage_tests,
                   key=lambda x: x['covered_count'], reverse=True)
        # denoted as output1
        print sa

        self.results['statements'].append(sa[0])
        # we don't care about it anymore
        del sa[0]

        # resort based on different criteria now
        sb = sorted(sa, cmp=self.compare_statements)
        # denoted as output2
        print sb

    def compare_statements(self, a, b):
        if len(a['covered'] - self.results['statements'][-1]['covered']) > \
            len(b['covered'] - self.results['statements'][-1]['covered']):
            return 1
        elif len(a['covered'] - self.results['statements'][-1]['covered']) < \
            len(b['covered'] - self.results['statements'][-1]['covered']):
            return -1
        else:
            return 0
```

## Print the `tests[x]['statements']`:

```
[{'id': 0, 'not_count': 12, 'covered_count': 48, 'coverage': {128: True, 132: False, 133: True, 134: False, 135: True, 136: False, 138: True, 139: True, 141: True, 148: True, 150: False, 151: False, 152: False, 153: False, 154: False, 155: False, 157: True, 158: True, 159: True, 160: True, 161: True, 162: True, 163: True, 164: True, 165: True, 166: True, 167: True, 168: True, 169: True, 171: True, 172: True, 173: False, 50: True, 51: True, 52: True, 53: True, 54: True, 58: True, 63: True, 72: True, 73: True, 75: True, 76: True, 79: False, 81: True, 90: True, 91: True, 93: True, 94: True, 97: False, 99: True, 104: True, 109: True, 118: True, 119: True, 120: True, 122: True, 124: True, 126: True, 127: True}, 'output': '0', 'not': set([97, 132, 134, 136, 173, 79, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155]), 'covered': set([128, 133, 135, 138, 139, 141, 148, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 171, 172, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 58, 63, 72, 73, 75, 76, 81, 90, 91, 93, 94, 99, 104, 109, 118, 119, 120, 122, 124, 126, 127])}, 
{'id': 1, 'not_count': 12, 'covered_count': 48, 'coverage': {128: True, 132: False, 133: True, 134: False, 135: True, 136: False, 138: True, 139: True, 141: True, 148: True, 150: False, 151: False, 152: False, 153: False, 154: False, 155: False, 157: True, 158: True, 159: True, 160: True, 161: True, 162: True, 163: True, 164: True, 165: True, 166: True, 167: True, 168: True, 169: True, 171: True, 172: True, 173: False, 50: True, 51: True, 52: True, 53: True, 54: True, 58: True, 63: True, 72: True, 73: True, 75: True, 76: True, 79: False, 81: True, 90: True, 91: True, 93: True, 94: True, 97: False, 99: True, 104: True, 109: True, 118: True, 119: True, 120: True, 122: True, 124: True, 126: True, 127: True}, 'output': '0', 'not': set([97, 132, 134, 136, 173, 79, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155]), 'covered': set([128, 133, 135, 138, 139, 141, 148, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 171, 172, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 58, 63, 72, 73, 75, 76, 81, 90, 91, 93, 94, 99, 104, 109, 118, 119, 120, 122, 124, 126, 127])}]
```

## Output1

```
[{'id': 0, 'not_count': 12, 'covered_count': 48, 'coverage': {128: True, 132: False, 133: True, 134: False, 135: True, 136: False, 138: True, 139: True, 141: True, 148: True, 150: False, 151: False, 152: False, 153: False, 154: False, 155: False, 157: True, 158: True, 159: True, 160: True, 161: True, 162: True, 163: True, 164: True, 165: True, 166: True, 167: True, 168: True, 169: True, 171: True, 172: True, 173: False, 50: True, 51: True, 52: True, 53: True, 54: True, 58: True, 63: True, 72: True, 73: True, 75: True, 76: True, 79: False, 81: True, 90: True, 91: True, 93: True, 94: True, 97: False, 99: True, 104: True, 109: True, 118: True, 119: True, 120: True, 122: True, 124: True, 126: True, 127: True}, 'output': '0', 'not': set([97, 132, 134, 136, 173, 79, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155]), 'covered': set([128, 133, 135, 138, 139, 141, 148, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 171, 172, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 58, 63, 72, 73, 75, 76, 81, 90, 91, 93, 94, 99, 104, 109, 118, 119, 120, 122, 124, 126, 127])}, 
{'id': 1, 'not_count': 12, 'covered_count': 48, 'coverage': {128: True, 132: False, 133: True, 134: False, 135: True, 136: False, 138: True, 139: True, 141: True, 148: True, 150: False, 151: False, 152: False, 153: False, 154: False, 155: False, 157: True, 158: True, 159: True, 160: True, 161: True, 162: True, 163: True, 164: True, 165: True, 166: True, 167: True, 168: True, 169: True, 171: True, 172: True, 173: False, 50: True, 51: True, 52: True, 53: True, 54: True, 58: True, 63: True, 72: True, 73: True, 75: True, 76: True, 79: False, 81: True, 90: True, 91: True, 93: True, 94: True, 97: False, 99: True, 104: True, 109: True, 118: True, 119: True, 120: True, 122: True, 124: True, 126: True, 127: True}, 'output': '0', 'not': set([97, 132, 134, 136, 173, 79, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155]), 'covered': set([128, 133, 135, 138, 139, 141, 148, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 171, 172, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 58, 63, 72, 73, 75, 76, 81, 90, 91, 93, 94, 99, 104, 109, 118, 119, 120, 122, 124, 126, 127])}, 
{'id': 0, 'not_count': 12, 'covered_count': 48, 'coverage': {128: True, 132: False, 133: True, 134: False, 135: True, 136: False, 138: True, 139: True, 141: True, 148: True, 150: False, 151: False, 152: False, 153: False, 154: False, 155: False, 157: True, 158: True, 159: True, 160: True, 161: True, 162: True, 163: True, 164: True, 165: True, 166: True, 167: True, 168: True, 169: True, 171: True, 172: True, 173: False, 50: True, 51: True, 52: True, 53: True, 54: True, 58: True, 63: True, 72: True, 73: True, 75: True, 76: True, 79: False, 81: True, 90: True, 91: True, 93: True, 94: True, 97: False, 99: True, 104: True, 109: True, 118: True, 119: True, 120: True, 122: True, 124: True, 126: True, 127: True}, 'output': '0', 'not': set([97, 132, 134, 136, 173, 79, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155]), 'covered': set([128, 133, 135, 138, 139, 141, 148, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 171, 172, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 58, 63, 72, 73, 75, 76, 81, 90, 91, 93, 94, 99, 104, 109, 118, 119, 120, 122, 124, 126, 127])}, 
{'id': 1, 'not_count': 12, 'covered_count': 48, 'coverage': {128: True, 132: False, 133: True, 134: False, 135: True, 136: False, 138: True, 139: True, 141: True, 148: True, 150: False, 151: False, 152: False, 153: False, 154: False, 155: False, 157: True, 158: True, 159: True, 160: True, 161: True, 162: True, 163: True, 164: True, 165: True, 166: True, 167: True, 168: True, 169: True, 171: True, 172: True, 173: False, 50: True, 51: True, 52: True, 53: True, 54: True, 58: True, 63: True, 72: True, 73: True, 75: True, 76: True, 79: False, 81: True, 90: True, 91: True, 93: True, 94: True, 97: False, 99: True, 104: True, 109: True, 118: True, 119: True, 120: True, 122: True, 124: True, 126: True, 127: True}, 'output': '0', 'not': set([97, 132, 134, 136, 173, 79, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155]), 'covered': set([128, 133, 135, 138, 139, 141, 148, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 171, 172, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 58, 63, 72, 73, 75, 76, 81, 90, 91, 93, 94, 99, 104, 109, 118, 119, 120, 122, 124, 126, 127])}]
```

## Output2:

```
[{'id': 1, 'not_count': 12, 'covered_count': 48, 'coverage': {128: True, 132: False, 133: True, 134: False, 135: True, 136: False, 138: True, 139: True, 141: True, 148: True, 150: False, 151: False, 152: False, 153: False, 154: False, 155: False, 157: True, 158: True, 159: True, 160: True, 161: True, 162: True, 163: True, 164: True, 165: True, 166: True, 167: True, 168: True, 169: True, 171: True, 172: True, 173: False, 50: True, 51: True, 52: True, 53: True, 54: True, 58: True, 63: True, 72: True, 73: True, 75: True, 76: True, 79: False, 81: True, 90: True, 91: True, 93: True, 94: True, 97: False, 99: True, 104: True, 109: True, 118: True, 119: True, 120: True, 122: True, 124: True, 126: True, 127: True}, 'output': '0', 'not': set([97, 132, 134, 136, 173, 79, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155]), 'covered': set([128, 133, 135, 138, 139, 141, 148, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 171, 172, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 58, 63, 72, 73, 75, 76, 81, 90, 91, 93, 94, 99, 104, 109, 118, 119, 120, 122, 124, 126, 127])}, 
{'id': 0', not_count': 12, 'covered_count': 48, 'coverage': {128: True, 132: False, 133: True, 134: False, 135: True, 136: False, 138: True, 139: True, 141: True, 148: True, 150: False, 151: False, 152: False, 153: False, 154: False, 155: False, 157: True, 158: True, 159: True, 160: True, 161: True, 162: True, 163: True, 164: True, 165: True, 166: True, 167: True, 168: True, 169: True, 171: True, 172: True, 173: False, 50: True, 51: True, 52: True, 53: True, 54: True, 58: True, 63: True, 72: True, 73: True, 75: True, 76: True, 79: False, 81: True, 90: True, 91: True, 93: True, 94: True, 97: False, 99: True, 104: True, 109: True, 118: True, 119: True, 120: True, 122: True, 124: True, 126: True, 127: True}, 'output': '0', 'not': set([97, 132, 134, 136, 173, 79, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155]), 'covered': set([128, 133, 135, 138, 139, 141, 148, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 171, 172, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 58, 63, 72, 73, 75, 76, 81, 90, 91, 93, 94, 99, 104, 109, 118, 119, 120, 122, 124, 126, 127])}, 
{'id': 1, 'not_count': 12, 'covered_count': 48, 'coverage': {128: True, 132: False, 133: True, 134: False, 135: True, 136: False, 138: True, 139: True, 141: True, 148: True, 150: False, 151: False, 152: False, 153: False, 154: False, 155: False, 157: True, 158: True, 159: True, 160: True, 161: True, 162: True, 163: True, 164: True, 165: True, 166: True, 167: True, 168: True, 169: True, 171: True, 172: True, 173: False, 50: True, 51: True, 52: True, 53: True, 54: True, 58: True, 63: True, 72: True, 73: True, 75: True, 76: True, 79: False, 81: True, 90: True, 91: True, 93: True, 94: True, 97: False, 99: True, 104: True, 109: True, 118: True, 119: True, 120: True, 122: True, 124: True, 126: True, 127: True}, 'output': '0', 'not': set([97, 132, 134, 136, 173, 79, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155]), 'covered': set([128, 133, 135, 138, 139, 141, 148, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 171, 172, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 58, 63, 72, 73, 75, 76, 81, 90, 91, 93, 94, 99, 104, 109, 118, 119, 120, 122, 124, 126, 127])}]
```

The expected output of this would be strictly `{'id': 1...}`  I don't even care about the accuracy of the sorting right now, I care strictly about the fact that sorted is adding copies of elements to the list.  It is quite difficult to give you a snippet to run and generate this on your own -- as the input for this is running programs against gcov and calculating their coverage.

Comment: You are *mutating* the list.

Comment: You have something weird looking in your initialisation loop - you look like you are mixing C-style loops `for i=0; i<length; i++` with iteration loops `for item in collection:`. Your code does `for test in self.tests: ... append(self.tests[test].get...`  and I think it should be `for test in self.tests: .. append(test.get(...`

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, no, the input is actually slightly different than the way I store it.  The input is an indexed array of dictionaries.  So "test" is actually an int (0,1,2,...n) and then I grab the index of test and get the dictionary key and place it where I need it.

Comment: `sorted` is not the source of your problems.  `sorted` iterates over a iterable and returns a new sorted list.  The only way `sorted` could have the side effect of mutating your list would be if your compare function did that (and it doesn't).  So look for your problem elsewhere.  To see this `print self.statement_coverage_tests` before sorting.  Then after sorting print the sorted result.  The lists will be of the same length.

Comment: @sobolevn, yes, I am mutating my list, but outside of the context of `sorted()`.
@StevenRumbalski, the `print the tests[x]['statements']` is the printing before the sorting.  The `output1` is after `sorted()` is called the first time, and `output2` is after `sorted()` is called the second time.

Comment: Your code is not running (eg `self.statement_coverage_tests` is not defined), please edit your question with working code so that we can reproduce your problem when we run it. After the code, please provide the sample input data we must feed to your code to produce what you see. Then after that show the output that is faulty. Then show what you are expecting.

Comment: ...@StevenRumablski was correct.  Apparently a tiny subset of my data (the subset I'm testing with, of course) is being added multiple times to the `tests` input from elsewhere in the program. #fml

Comment: The hardest part of fixing a bug is when its not where you think it is.  Happens to everyone.